# Expressão regular para identificar caixa de texto em formulário HTML

Tags: html, android, regex

#### Situação

Dar-se uma página em HTML qualquer no qual encontra-se um formulário contendo, a princípio, duas caixas de texto, sendo uma para nome e outra para o e-mail.  Surgiu então a necessidade, para fazer alguns testes no Android, de obter apenas um trecho do código e jogar em uma lista, porém tentei de algumas formas criar uma expressão regular para resgatar essa parte código mas não obtive sucesso. Esta sendo usado a biblioteca `org.apache.http.legacy` pare obtenção do código fonte onde não foi encontrado nenhuma barreira na leitura do código seguinte.

#### Código

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
          <form>
             <label for="nome">Nome</label>
             <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome"/><br><br>
             <label for="email">email</label>
             <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><br><br>
             <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

#### Dúvida

Gostaria de usar o regex para identificar exatamente o começo e o fim de cada `input`, sendo `<input` e o `/>`, assim para esse HTML resultaria por exemplo em dois itens:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" id="male"/>
<input type="text" name="nome" id="male"/>
```

Depois da identificação, pretendo jogar cada input dentro de um `array` (Mas essa parte é tranquila). Alguém poderia me ajudar com essa expressão? Abraços!

**Obs.:** A expressão neste caso, seria independente da linguagem. Se eu vou usar tal método ou tal linguagem (java, c#, javascript), ai usarei as `libs` necessárias para o tratamento do `regex`.

Abraços! =)

Comment: HTML não é uma linguagem regular. Expressões regulares só resolveriam seu problema se seu HTML fosse bastante previsível e limitado. O que você provavelmente precisa é de um _parser_ de HTML. Tome cuidado com os [problemas XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy).

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Eu não disse que é! Como a ideia é usar no Android, então a linguagem de programação nativa é JAVA. Mas a expressão neste caso, é independente da linguagem. Se eu vou usar tal método ou tal linguagem (java, c#, javascript), ai posso usar as `libs` necessárias para o tratamento do `regex`. Abraços.

Comment: @CleidimarViana O que o Pablo Almeida quis dizer é que muito dificilmente você vai conseguir encontrar um regex que seja satisfatório pra resolver seu problema, porque HTML é uma linguagem [complexa demais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarquia_de_Chomsky) pro que o regex consegue resolver. A melhor solução nesse caso é usar um parser. Ao invés de procurar uma lib pra lidar com regex, procure um parser praquela linguagem. Se você indicar a sua favorita na pergunta, tenho certeza de que alguém pode recomendar um.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a seguinte expressão: `<\s* input [^>]+ >/xg`

```
<
```

Coincide com "<" literalmente

```
\S
```

*corresponderá a qualquer caractere espaço em branco [\ r \ n \ t \ f].*

```
*
```

*entre zero e ilimitadas vezes, tantas vezes quanto possível, dando a volta conforme necessário [ganancioso].*

```
input
```

*casa com a palavra leteralmente (case sensitive).*

```
[^>]+
```

*corresponder a um único caractere não presente na lista.*

```
+
```

*entre um e ilimitadas vezes, tantas vezes quanto possível, dando a volta conforme necessário [gananciosos].*

```
>
```

*carácter único na lista, ">" literal (case sensitive).*

```
>
```

*coincide com ">" literalmente.*

```
/g
```

*modificador global, não para na primeira ocorrência.*

```
/x
```

*modificador estendido ignora espaço em branco e comentários.*

Teste e explicação (inglês) : [Regex_input_tag](https://regex101.com/r/xS7oU9/1)

Mais sobre Regex: [Aurélio Regex](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/metacaracteres.html)

Comment: Acho que vai dar certo assim! Vlw

Comment: Qq coisa comenta e ajustamos...

Comment: Claro! Abraços.

Comment: Teria como você editar sua resposta e inserir uma descrição para a expressão. Tipo, explicando o que cada trecho faz. abs.